# Overcoming skolemization via unsafeCoerce

Tags: haskell, ambiguous, type-deduction

Is there any way to overcome skolemization through `unsafeCoerce`? Consider the following scenario:

```
data BlackBox = forall a. BlackBox a

mkBlackBox :: a -> (BlackBox, Proxy a)
mkBlackBox x = (BlackBox x, Proxy)

getBlackBox :: Proxy a -> BlackBox -> a
getBlackBox Proxy (BlackBox x) = unsafeCoerce x
```

if you run this code, you'll find that if `unsafeCoerce :: a1 -> b` and `BlackBox :: a -> BlackBox`, then `a1` does not unify with `a`. Is there any hope to staple this together, and just assume it works?

Comment: I'm basically looking for a language extension or something that allows for `data BlackBox = BlackBox {-# UNSKOLEMIZE #-} (forall a. a)`, so that this ambiguity can be explicitly ignored, s.t. `x :: a` in this example allows `a` to be brought to the top level

Comment: `unsafeCoerce` isn't doing anything here. The problem is putting `x` *into* `BlackBox`, not getting it out. Maybe you meant to make an existential type?

Comment: But the specification `getBlackBox :: Proxy a -> BlackBox -> a` is wrong! It says "for any type `a` of your choice I can turn any `BlackBox` into a value of that type". In reality you can only retrieve an `a` if the value in the `BlackBox` was an `a` all along: you can't get a `Bool` out of a `BlackBox`containing an `Int`. To make this work you'd need a [`Typeable a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Typeable.html#t:Typeable) dictionary. I suggest you review the design of the [`Dynamic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Data-Dynamic.html) library.

Comment: I suspect this may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Do not do this - use `GHC.Prim.Any`, which is a "black box" for which it is explicitly safe to do this (you don't need the proxy argument). If you were going to do this, then the datatype you want is `data BlackBox = forall a . BlackBox a` - the type `forall a . a` does not unify with some arbitrary type `a'` and `unsafeCoerce` cannot do anything to help here (nor are there any language extensions to turn this off, other than `-fdefer-type-errors`). Your `BlackBox` does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: Thank you @user2407038 - I think Dynamic is the option I was actually looking for

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson You're exactly correct with this. Sorry about the funny type definition, that was actually a typo. I was wondering how this could be accomplished, but `fromDynamic` does it perfectly!

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, the `Dynamic` library won't have a design worthy of imitation till GHC 8.2, when `Typeable` is expected to get massively overhauled.

Comment: @dfeuer `Typeable` seems to get massively overhauled every three weeks

Comment: @BenjaminHodgson, that may be, but the overhaul currently in the works seems to come pretty close to what one would actually *want* `Typeable` to be.

Comment: Specifically, you'll be able to *use* the structural information in the `TypeRep` in all sorts of ways that you currently can't, because it will be, or perhaps pretend to be, GADT-like.